# use of cairngormEvent in cairngorm framework

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm

What is the use to event extend the cairngorm event in cairngorm framework.?

Can anyone explain about the cairngorm event.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cairngorm event is a decouple way to call the command. which is command will call specific business process.

it should extends CairngormEvent because cairngorm event has its own dispatching mechanism. cairngorm event can be dispatched only by calling its dispatch() method.